# SharePoinr 2016 on prem not incremental syncing profiles when using FBA

Tags: sharepoint-server, forms-authentication, profile-sync, incremental-crawl

I think that this question belongs to this community:

I have just installed a on prem SP 2016 and created a My site hos web application that uses FBA. I configured the web config files to read the users from AD according to this guide:

How to Configure Forms-Based Authentication with AD in SharePoint 2010/2013

The problem is that the incremental sync is not working at all. When I add a user to AD this user doesn't get synced with SP.

I did another test by creating a new SP 2016 farm and a My site host web application but this time using windows authentication and the incremental sync works without any problem.

Do you know if there is a bug or some special configuration when using FBA and make incremental sync works?

Best regards Americo

Answer (score 0):

**Navigate to Central Administration**:
->Manage service applications
->User Profile service application
->configure synchronization connections
->create a new connection that Authentication Provider Type is selected Forms authentication.

Comment: Thanks. I did that and it seems to solve the sync problem but another one arised now. When the user log in for first time he/she is presented with the onde drive page. Once the user clicked "next" the page showing the message that the site is being created is shown and nothing else happens. I checked the timer jobb and it says succeded but not site collection is created. I check the server log and an error message says that the user can not be found.
Why? I can see the user in the SP profile!